# How to get Enum object by value in C#?

Tags: c#, object, enums, helper, enumerable

I recently encountered a case when I needed to get an **Enum** object by value (to be saved via EF CodeFirst), and here is my **Enum**:

```
public enum ShipmentStatus {
  New = 0,
  Shipped = 1,
  Canceled = 2
}
```

So I needed to get `ShipmentStatus.Shipped` object by value **1**.

So how could I accomplish that?

Comment: This is a good Q, though it's been discussed before on multiple threads.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not use this build in feature?

```
ShipmentStatus shipped = (ShipmentStatus)System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(ShipmentStatus)).GetValue(1);
```

Answer (score 11):

This should work, either (just casting the `int` value to `enum` type):

```
int _val = 1;
ShipmentStatus _item = (ShipmentStatus)_val;
```

Beware, that it may cause an error if that enum is not defined.

Comment: hmm didn't think about this. a lot shorter :)

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda "short-cut" :-)

Answer (score 1):

After some battling with **Enum** I created this - a universal helper class that will do what I needed - getting key by value, and more importantly - from ANY **Enum** type:

```
public static class EnumHelpers {

  public static T GetEnumObjectByValue<T>(int valueId) {
    return (T) Enum.ToObject(typeof (T), valueId);
  }

}
```

So, to get **Enum** object `ShipmentStatus.Shipped` this will return this object:

```
var enumObject = EnumHelpers.GetEnumObjectByValue<ShipmentStatus>(1);
```

So basicaly you can use any **Enum** object and get its key by value:

```
var enumObject = EnumHelpers.GetEnumObjectByValue<YOUR_ENUM_TYPE>(VALUE);
```

Comment: You might want to add a check to make sure the value is valid for the `Enum`.  According the the documentation for `Enum.ToObject` it does not do that check.  You can use `Enum.IsDefined` for that.

Comment: Exactly right! Otherwise, the conversion is just a line of code.